# ¿Como obtener la mayor cantidad de caracteres guardada en una columna de una tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla `products` donde la columna `code` es un `TINYTEXT`.
Al intentar crear una *clave foránea* (`FOREING KEY`) obtengo este error:

> #1170 - Columna BLOB column 'code' usada en especificación de clave sin tamaño de la clave

Dado que [no se puede crear claves foráneas usando campos `tinytext`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1827099/3791844) (*entre otros*), decidí convertir la columna `code` a `VARCHAR`, pero, para definir correctamente la longitud del `VARCHAR` necesito saber:

¿Cuantos caracteres tiene el código mas largo guardado en la tabla?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pude obtener el resultado usando [`CHAR_LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length).

> Devuelve la longitud de la cadena `str`, medida en caracteres.

#### Solución:

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(code) AS codeLength
FROM products
ORDER BY codeLength DESC
LIMIT 1
```

#### Explicación:

Con `SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(code) AS codeLength` obtengo la cantidad de caracteres que tiene el `code` de cada producto.

Al agregar `ORDER BY codeLength DESC`, obtengo los productos ordenados por su longitud de caracteres de mayor a menor, es decir, *los que tienen el código con mas caracteres primero*.

Y finalmente con `LIMIT 1`, obtengo solo el primero.

Comment: Muy buena solución! Yo ya estaba pensando en utilizar regex en conjunto con otras cosas. Me ha servido para simplificar bastante el proceso. Gracias!